# $\omega$-regular expression to LTL

Tags: regular-expressions, linear-temporal-logic

Is there any systematic (algorithmic) method to convert an $\omega$-regular expression like

$
(a^∗)(b)(b^∗)(a^∗)(c^\omega)
$

to an LTL property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LTL is less expressive than $\omega$-regular expressions. For example, the expression 
$$((a+b)b)^\omega$$
i.e. "there is $b$ in all the even places" 
cannot be expressed in LTL.

In addition, observe that checking whether an $\omega$ regular expression is expressible in LTL is harder than checking universality, which is PSPACE hard.

However, there are ways to tackle this problem. You can start [here](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/DG-WT08.pdf) for a reference.

Comment: Is there an algorithm that convert an $\omega$-regular expression to its equivalent Buchi automaton?

Comment: Sure. It's almost identical to the corresponding algorithm for regular expressions and DFAs. Just construct recursively.